# JavaScript object.hasOwnProperty(proName) vs lodash _.has(obj, proName) function

Tags: javascript, properties, lodash

I'm debating between using JavaScript `Object.hasOwnProperty(propName)` and lodash `_.has(obj, proName)` function to determine if an object has a property.

Which is more efficient for simple cases? For complex cases? For all cases?

Is there a better library that I haven't mentioned?

Thanks!

Comment: What would be a complex case of checking a property on an object?

Comment: I guess I'm referring to nested cases.

Comment: You can always check their own method and see if it fits your needs or you could do with less: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.2.1-npm-packages/lodash.has/index.js

Comment: Well, try both on `{hasOwnProperty: function(){ return false; }}` and `"hasOwnProperty"`…

Answer (score 33):

Well the Lodash `_.has()` method is just a call to `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` after a check for a null argument. The code grabs a reference early on:

```
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
```

and then `_.has(object, prop)` looks like

```
return object != null && hasOwnProperty.call(object, prop);
```

Comment: It is expecting prop as 'prop' if you are passing property direct.

Comment: this is allegedly better practice b/c the object's actual hasOwnProperty could be shadowed, and the case where it is a null object (Object.create(null)).

Comment: @CraigAllen but `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(null, prop)` returns `false` anyway so the initial `object != null` is just a waste?

Comment: @Friendly-Robot it could be a performance thing to avoid making a function call.

Answer (score 0):

In version 4.17.21 of lodash they are quite different, as seen below, and that may lead to unpredictable results:

```
var baseHas = require('./_baseHas'),
    hasPath = require('./_hasPath');

function has(object, path) {
  return object != null && hasPath(object, path, baseHas);
}
```